# Why aren't my post showing under my custom menu?

Tags: menus

I have tried everything I've read through google search as well as through the wordpress forums and support. I have created the custom menus using the categories and adding my post I write with the proper categories in hopes they will show on my webpage but when i go to my page it's now showing anything I post anywhere and when I go through my dashboard click on a published post and hit view it sends me to my page with an error message saying the content I was trying to find isn't available. What am I doing wrong?!?!?! I want to take my page off maintence and start working on views but it's difficult when i have ZERO content wanting to show under my tabs no matter what I do. I've posted a screen shot on this question to show how I've created my custom menu
[image]

Comment: do you have the category.php template in your theme folder?

Answer (score 0):

For the error message "not available": have you tried rebuilding your permalinks?

Try: Admin > Aettings > Permalinks

…then hit "save changes" to rebuild the permalinks. I hope this helps to solve the issue.